# identifying general phrases in a particular dialect

Tags: nlp, nltk, opennlp

I am looking for an algorithm or method that would help identify general phrases from a corpus of text that has a particular dialect (it is from a specific domain but for my case is a dialect of the English language) -- for example the following fragment could be from a larger corpus related to the World or Warcraft or perhaps MMORPHs.

> players control a character avatar within a game world in third person or first person view, exploring the landscape, fighting various monsters, completing quests, and interacting with non-player characters (NPCs) or other players. Also similar to other MMORPGs, World of Warcraft requires the player to pay for a subscription, either by buying prepaid game cards for a selected amount of playing time, or by using a credit or debit card to pay on a regular basis

As output from the above I would like to identify the following general phrases:

1. first person
2. World of Warcraft
3. prepaid game cards
4. debit card

Notes:

1. There is a previous questions similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164614/extracting-nouns-noun-phrases-adjectives-verbs-from-text-file-corpus-using-visua) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708047/how-to-extract-the-noun-phrases-using-open-nlps-chunking-parser) but for clarification mine has the following differences:

   a. I am trying to use an existing toolkit such as NLTK, OpenNLP, etc.

   b. I am not interested in identifying other Parts of Speech in the sentence

   c. I can use human intervention where the algorithm presents the identified noun phrases to a human expert and the human expert can then confirm or reject the findings however we do not have resources for training a model of language on hand-annotated data

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did you compile the WoW chat corpus?

Comment: Oh that was just an example - the real target application is for a vertical domain that would be a poor example.

Comment: you might be interested in this thread: http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1309&L=CORPORA&F=&S=&P=23253

Answer (score 1):

Nltk has built in part of speech tagging that has proven pretty good at identifying unknown words. That said, you seem to misunderstand what a noun is and you should probably solidify your understanding of both parts of speech, and your question.

For instance, in `first person` first is an adjective. You could automatically assume that associated adjectives are a part of that phrase.

Alternately, if you're looking to identify general phrases my suggestion would be to implement a simple Markov Chain model and then look for especially high transition probabilities.

If you're looking for a Markov Chain implementation in Python I would point you towards this gist that I wrote up back in the day: https://gist.github.com/Slater-Victoroff/6227656

If you want to get much more advanced than that, you're going to quickly descend into dissertation territory. I hope that helps.

P.S. Nltk includes a huge number of pre-annotated corpuses that might work for your purposes.

Comment: Many thanks Slater, I believe I'm looking for general phrases - so for example "to be or not to be" would be a phrase that I'd like to identify.

Comment: @user1172468 I would definitely suggest using the markoc chain method then.

Comment: would you know of a case study or tutorial that discusses something similar.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to do noun phrase extraction. The [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org) Python library includes two noun phrase extraction implementations out of the box.

The simplest way to get started is to use the default `FastNPExtractor` which is based of Shlomi Babluki's algorithm described [here](http://thetokenizer.com/2013/05/09/efficient-way-to-extract-the-main-topics-of-a-sentence/).

```
from text.blob import TextBlob

text = '''
players control a character avatar within a game world in third person or first
person view, exploring the landscape, fighting various monsters, completing quests,
and interacting with non-player characters (NPCs) or other players. Also similar
to other MMORPGs, World of Warcraft requires the player to pay for a
subscription, either by buying prepaid game cards for a selected amount of
playing time, or by using a credit or debit card to pay on a regular basis
'''

blob = TextBlob(text)
print(blob.noun_phrases)  # ['players control', 'character avatar' ...]
```

Swapping out for the other implementation (an NLTK-based chunker) is quite easy.

```
from text.np_extractors import ConllExtractor

blob = TextBlob(text, np_extractor=ConllExtractor())

print(blob.noun_phrases)  # ['character avatar', 'game world' ...]
```

If neither of these suffice, you can create your own noun phrase extractor class. I recommend looking at the [TextBlob np_extractor module source](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/master/text/np_extractors.py) for examples. To gain a better understanding of noun phrase chunking, check out the [NLTK book, Chapter 7](http://nltk.org/book/ch07.html).